# create image slider that shows part of previous and next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

I'm trying to create a slideshow using jQuery (similar to [jquery scrollhorz](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html)) but I want the previous and next image partly shown.

Right now, what I have, is a div (with overflow hidden) containing all the images I have. When previous or next button is pressed, I animate the whole div either to left or right. The problem is, if I have many images loaded into the div, it becomes laggy and slow.

What is the best design to implement this image slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the code required, my suggestion would be to use jquery (or moo if that's your thing) to maintain a div that is three to five images long, and keep a list of urls to all the images you want displayed. When you slide the images left or right, you'll pop off the image on the opposite end and add the appropriate image to the other side.

You could use the same technique to loop through the list seamlessly.

Comment: if I pop up an image from one end and add the new image to the other end, how would I do the animation of scrolling left to right or vice versa?

Comment: Use an internal div to house the images that is larger than the container (viewport) and just move the entire inner div like you are now. The viewport would just be hidden overflow.

Comment: that is what i'm currently doing right now. It becomes slow whenever I have too many images. I think the problem is because the images are big and gets resized to fit the container (that's my settings). Thanks for the help tho

Comment: if you're using jquery to remove images from the inner div as it scrolls, there's no way you can ever have "too many images" in it. You'll only ever have the number you specify.

Comment: example: user clicks "Scroll left". You scroll the div to the appropriate position, and then use jquery to entirely remove the right-most image. You then use jquery to add the next image in the list to the left-most side. The image has slid over, you can see the images next to it, and your inner div still has only the number of images you want.

Comment: Finally figure it out. I think this is a lot better than loading all images. Thanks a lo!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

[Hero carousel](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/)

It fits your description....Hope it helps out :)

this might be a solution too.
http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/15/ 
Vote up if it helps you :) all the best