# Show part of previous and next slide in Swiper

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to show part of the previous and next slide in swiper, but using config like "slidesPerView: 2.2" always shows part of the next slide but never part of the previous one. See these examples:

First Slide
[image: example1]

Second Slide
[image: example2]

what i actually want:

[image: example3]

Any ideas?

Btw this question here is related but doesn't give the answer I was looking for: [Swiper slides - showing end/start of previous/next slides like Airbnb Slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406690/swiper-slides-showing-end-start-of-previous-next-slides-like-airbnb-slider)

Answer (score 3):

```
slidesPerView: 1.2,
centeredSlides: true,
spaceBetween: 10,
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a conflicting config using slidesOffsetBefore and slidesOffsetAfter in conjunction with centeredSlides. centeredSlides works as expected if I remove those and then I am getting the result I described above.